# Static - Good or Bad?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, optimization, static

Alright, so I've been trying to figure out this for far too long now.

I've read countless articles/questions on `static`, and also singletons.

This is how I have been using static for quite some time:

I have a GameManager.cs, which has TileMap.cs & Player.cs. TileMap.cs needs to access the player's camera, for updating the position of the map:

```
GameManager.cs:

public static TileMap map;
public static Player player;

Update code, draw, etc. below...
```

There will only be one of each of these.

```
TileMap.cs:

Vector2 mapPosition = new Vector2(GameManager.Player.position.X, GameManager.Player.position.Y);
```

Is this acceptable? What downsides are there to this?

Edit: Seeing as though this question is too broad, let me see if I can be more specific.

**Is there a better way to do this rather than through static methods? I have multiple lists of classes inside TileMap.cs, some of which have Lists inside of them (thinking mostly of my particle engine), so would `Update(Player player)` be more efficient, or would it not really matter?**

P.S, I have noticed when the player moves the game map sort of "jitters" (lags for a small fraction of a second). Could this be causing it?

Thanks,
Shyy

Comment: Learn programming patterns. static is a very small part of it.

Comment: That is a very generic question.

Static can be good and bad, however for the usage you are doing I don't really see why you are using static.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed similar questions quite often professionally. So let me give you a straight answer, of which I am well aware that it doens't apply to the general case. See it as an opinion of what I consider 'best practice for beginners'.

`static` is often used for making variables available across class boundaries, as-if they are singletons. The singleton pattern here is just a design pattern wrapper (which doesn't solve most of the problems). While this might make programs easier to write, using `static` can also make programs much more complex if you want to make your application multi-threaded.

*In general I therefore think it's a good idea to avoid using `static` alltogether and simply pass objects around.*

There is one exception, that is: if you need to have data that is accessible across thread boundaries. If this is the case, you'll quickly find yourself in a world of hurt, and it is best to learn as much as you can about locking and use that for all static variables (including their members if they are structures/classes!).

If that isn't good enough as well, you can continue on that path and learn about things like interlocked and memory barriers (but I wouldn't recommend that if you don't need it).

Fortunately, most applications are fast enough to work in a single thread. I imagine your application to be no exception (and you can probably use a standard game framework to do the multi-threaded part of the application -- PS: if so, be careful with class variables as well, since they might be passed across thread boundaries as well).

As for your lag: I think you should use a good profiler to find performance hotspots; it's probably unrelated to the use of `static`.

Answer (score 2):

As you are asking about downsides:

1) does the code that uses `static` variables involved in muti threading ? 
   If yes, you may consider locking management. Which easily makes apparently easy code complicated.

2) Are `Player`, `position` and others structures ? If so, every time accessing them via property, you create a copy of instances and not access to the references directly. Considering that code provided  some `2D` engine, and you are creating a `Vector`, so probably some rendering pipeline code, this may introduce some serious performance implications.